# Where to put (-) hyphen in yaml ansible play books?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am very confused, in the play book where actually we put single hyphen (-). I found similar threads here, but still confused, so decided to draft one new. I have read it will be used to indicate start of a list item. again i have difficulty in understanding where is the start of list and where is start of dictionary. 
Can some experts explain me where should i put hyphen in below code. and why is that?

```
---
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: rtr
  tasks:
      name: "read configs"
      read_csv:
        path: "{{ aws_config }}"
      register: aws_requests
      run_once: true

      debug:
        msg: "{{ aws_requests.list }}"
      name: "display awsconfigs requests"
      run_once: true

      name: "set awsconfigs requests"
      run_once: true
      set_fact:
        aws_configs: "{{ aws_requests.list }}"

      name: "build template"
      template:
        dest: "{{ config_filename }}"
        lstrip_blocks: true
        src: "{{ template }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you read the "[Intro to playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html)", which should answer your questions, but below is a summary.

As you noted correctly, hyphens are list items in YAML. YAML documents start with `---`, which is why there are **hyphens at the start of the file**.

The starting point for any Ansible playbook is the **playbook** itself in the file. The playbook file itself may contain one or more so-called "**plays**", **each as its own list element**. Each play typically contains a `hosts` and a `tasks` part. In many playbooks, there is just one "play", so your typical minimal playbook looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  tasks:
  - name: Task 1
    ...
```

As you can see above, each "play" then has a **list of tasks**, each starting with a hyphen. So in the following example there are two tasks, each with a `name` and the module (`yum` and `service` in this case):

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  tasks:
  - name: ensure apache is at the latest version
    yum:
      name: httpd
      state: latest
  - name: ensure apache is running
    service:
      name: httpd
      state: started
```

Each Ansible module has different arguments, so you'll need to check the [modules documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/modules_by_category.html) for each one how to specify these arguments.

So the correct version for your playbook above would look like this:

```
---
- connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: rtr
  tasks:
  - name: "read configs"
    read_csv:
      path: "{{ aws_config }}"
    register: aws_requests
    run_once: true

  - name: "display awsconfigs requests"
    debug:
      msg: "{{ aws_requests.list }}"
    run_once: true

  - name: "set awsconfigs requests"
    run_once: true
    set_fact:
      aws_configs: "{{ aws_requests.list }}"

  - name: "build template"
    template:
      dest: "{{ config_filename }}"
      lstrip_blocks: true
      src: "{{ template }}"
```